# Attempt to formulate solution to coupled PDEs via variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms, greens-function

I have the following PDEs that I would like to solve for $f(x,\omega)$
and $g(x,\omega)$:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}-\omega^{4}f & =-\omega\dfrac{\partial{\cal B}}{\partial x}-a\omega^{3},\\
\dfrac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial x^{2}}-\omega^{4}g & =-\omega{\cal B}(x)
\end{align*}

where ${\cal B}(x)$ is an unknown function of $x$.

Is the correct way to use variation of parameters to write down the
solution of these equations
\begin{align*}
f(x,\omega) & =\dfrac{1}{2\omega^{2}}e^{\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{1}(\omega)}^{x}e^{-\omega^{2}\xi}\left(-\omega\dfrac{\partial{\cal B}}{\partial\xi}+a\omega^{3}\right){\rm d}\xi-\dfrac{1}{2\omega^{2}}e^{-\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{2}(\omega)}^{x}e^{\omega^{2}\xi}\left(-\omega\dfrac{\partial{\cal B}}{\partial\xi}+a\omega^{3}\right){\rm d}\xi\qquad(\dagger)\\
g(x,\omega) & =\dfrac{\omega}{2}e^{\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{3}(\omega)}^{x}e^{-\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi+\dfrac{\omega}{2}e^{-\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{4}(\omega)}^{x}e^{\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi.\qquad(\ddagger)
\end{align*}

where $p_{1}(\omega)$, $p_{2}(\omega)$, $p_{3}(\omega)$ and $p_{4}(\omega)$
are arbitrary functions of $\omega$? I am aware that when variation
of parameters is used to solve ODEs, that the lower limits of the
integrals are arbitrary constants, and are determined by the boundary conditions.

If we also know that $f$ is an even function of $x$ and $g$ and $\cal{B}$ are
odd functions of $x$, then (correct me if I've got this wrong)
one can show that $p_{1}(\omega)=-p_{2}(\omega)$ and $p_{3}(\omega)=-p_{4}(\omega)$.
However, suppose we also know that $f$ and $g$ satisfy
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\omega^{2}g(x,\omega)+\omega{\cal B}(x)=0\qquad(\star)
$$

Then (I think) one can show that
\begin{align*}
0 & =-\omega a\left(1-\cosh\omega^{2}x\right)\\
 & \phantom{=}-\dfrac{1}{2\omega}\left(e^{\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{1}(\omega)}^{x}e^{-\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi-e^{-\omega^{2}x}\int_{-p_{1}(\omega)}^{x}e^{\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi\right)\\
 & \phantom{=}-\dfrac{\omega^{3}}{2}\left(e^{\omega^{2}x}\int_{p_{3}(\omega)}^{x}e^{-\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi-e^{-\omega^{2}x}\int_{-p_{3}(\omega)}^{x}e^{\omega^{2}\xi}{\cal B}(\xi){\rm d}\xi\right).
\end{align*}

It is far from obvious what the relationship between $p_{1}(\omega)$
and $p_{3}(\omega)$ is in this case - despite the (almost) symmetry
between the integrals, even setting $p_{1}(\omega)=0$ doesn't really
help. Furthermore, it doesn't seem $p_{1}(\omega)$ and $p_{3}(\omega)$
will be functions of $\omega$ only, based on what I have tried.

Is it possible to use equation $(\star)$ to derive a relationship
between these functions?

As a more fundamental question, are $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$
the correct ways to bring in arbtirary functions in this problem?
If not, what else should I try?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{B}$ an unknown function _to be found from the equations_ or does it represent an _arbitrary_ function that is to be given? Because if it is the former then you don't have enough equations to get a unique solution.

Comment: In this case it's actually a function to be determined from the solution to the un-transformed problem (since these PDEs are the result of applying a Fourier sine transform to a specific problem). I'm aware that this will result in an integral equation which isn't easy to solve.